# Broken Card Reader. Dmesg getting spammed

Tags: ubuntu, usb, dmesg

Last Month I've bought a old Notebook. Its awesome, the only catch is, it has a broken Card Reader (0bda:0138). This is not a big deal. The real problem is dmesg is getting spammed with errors. Every second it is getting spammed with these errors:

```
[ 7731.105960] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 127 using ehci-pci
[ 7731.530004] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 127, error -71
[ 7731.610042] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 7731.701985] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 7731.902020] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 7732.090062] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 7732.182007] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 7732.382036] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 7732.490133] usb 1-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

My question is: Is there a way to block these errors, or the communication with the Card Reader?
The Card reader is not shown in lsusb.

My System is running a minimal Ubuntu 17.04 on Linux 4.10.
Notebook Model: Fujitsu Lifebook A512

Comment: 1st option I would check: can you turn it off in BIOS?

Comment: I did. There is no such option. I also did a BIOS Update and a CMOS reset.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the kernel is stepping through the device numbers when re-detecting the device, so using the USB device number to target the misbehaving device won't work. But it looks like the `1-1.2` part is stable...

Try this:

```
echo '1-1.2' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

Source: https://karlcode.owtelse.com/blog/2017/01/09/disabling-usb-ports-on-linux/

Alternatively:

```
echo disabled | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.2/power/wakeup
echo suspend | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.2/power/level
```

Source: slightly modified from [this answer on AskUbuntu.SE](https://askubuntu.com/a/750455/769591).